# DRF ModelViewSet queryset return results that their date is greater than or equal to today

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets, drf-queryset

I am using Django Rest Framework.

In the queryset I'm trying to filter my objects based on IF their Date is greater than or equal to today. Like so:

```
class DateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API Endpoint to retrieve all dates after today.
    """
    serializer_class = DateSerializer
    today = datetime.date.today()
    queryset = EventDate.objects.filter(end_date__gte=today)
```

But this ends up showing the past dates as well.

my serializer:

```
class DateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EventDate
        fields = ('start_date', 'end_date')
```

And then I pass it on to the Event Serializer:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    dates = DateSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'},
        }
```

My goal is when my API returns all events it should not return all dates that have been in the past.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `today = datetime.date.today()` will be evaluated when you *construct* the class, not each time when you need to fetch these attributes.

You can override the `get_queryset` method to fetch make a query with the date when the request is made:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class DateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API Endpoint to retrieve all dates after today.
    """
    serializer_class = DateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        EventDate.objects.filter(end_date__gte=now().date())
```

Comment: Great answer explaination.

Comment: Hey Willem, Thanks for your reply! The problem I have now is that the queryset does not affect the values in the EventSerializer (dates = DateSerializer). My goal is to filter and pass the dates to the EventSerializer

Comment: @TonyKyriakidis: but then you need an `EventViewSet` I think? You can filter with `Event.objects.filter(eventdate__end_date__gte=now().date())` (where `eventdate` is the `ForeignKey` from `Event` to `EventDate`, this might be a different name).